# Access CSV Data Set Config variables in backend listener

Tags: csv, jmeter

I'm trying to fetch my variables from CSV Data config and add them to my [backend listener](https://github.com/adrianmo/jmeter-backend-azure) in a distributed testing environment like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/jmeter-aci-terraform/jmeter-aci-terraform/). FYI, it works on my local machine.

Here is my test plan:

[Test Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ujl6.png)

CSV Data Config:

[CSV config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcoLh.png)

My csv looks like this:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM github_events;simpleQuery
SELECT count(*) FROM github_events;medium
SELECT count(*) FROM github_events;complexQuery
SELECT count(*) FROM github_events;simpleQuery
```

Backend Listener:

[Backend Listener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJerB.png)

I'm setting the CSV config variables in the beanshell pre-processor like this:

```
props.put("query", "${QUERY}");
props.put("query_type", "${QUERY_TYPE}");
```

and that's why I have the `${__P(query)}` `${__P(query_type)}` in the backend listener.

The goal is to grab the `QUERY` and `QUERY_TYPE` from the CSV data config and send it to the backend listener.

Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if I need to add more info on here. Thank you!

**Solution**:

How I got this to work... kind of hacky but it'll work for what I need:

I created a JSR223 Postprocessor on my JDBC Request and added the following code:

```
import groovy.json.*

def my_query = vars.get("QUERY")
def my_query_type = vars.get("QUERY_TYPE")

json = JsonOutput.toJson([myQuery: my_query, myQueryType: my_query_type])
prev.setSamplerData(groovy.json.JsonOutput.prettyPrint(groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(json)))
```

This won't work if you need whatever is in your response Data but in my case, it was okay to replace. BTW, this only works with my distributed test. To make it work locally, you use `prev.setResponseData` instead. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can, as per JMeter 5.4.1 all fields of the Backend Listener are being populated in ["testStarted" phase](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/src/components/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/visualizers/backend/BackendListener.java#L280)

the same applies to your [custom listener](https://github.com/adrianmo/jmeter-backend-azure/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/adrianmo/jmeter/backendlistener/azure/AzureBackendClient.java#L118)

it means that [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) originating from the CSV Data Set Config don't exist at the time the Backend Listener is being initialized and your reference to JMeter Properties returns the default value of `1` as there are no such variables.

If you're looking for the possibility to dynamically send metrics to Azure you will need to replicate the code from the Azure Backend Listener in [JSR223 Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) using [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) language.

---

The only way how this could work on your local machine is that:

1. You run your test plan in GUI mode 1st time - it fails, but it sets the properties
2. You run your test plan in GUI mode 2nd time - it passes but uses the last values of the properties
3. etc.

Comment: I thought because of the execution order, the listener would be hit last, including the all the fields but that isn't the case. in the [custom listener](https://github.com/adrianmo/jmeter-backend-azure/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/adrianmo/jmeter/backendlistener/azure/AzureBackendClient.java#L118) code, would it be possible to fetch the CSV fields at the start of the test? Thanks for always being helpful, Dmitri! I appreciate it.